# How do I validate integer field if user input nothing?

Tags: java, swing

```
do{
         try{
            input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Food quantity","Dope Alley",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            quantity = Integer.parseInt(input);
            if(quantity <= 0 || quantity > 100){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input . Number only .\n\nMininum order = 1\nMaximum order = 100","Dope Alley",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid input . Number only .\n\nMininum order = 1\nMaximum order = 100","Dope Alley",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }while(quantity <= 0 || quantity > 100);
```

catch(NumberFormatException e) how to clarify variable e in my code? in my code the program stated that variable e is not used . so how can i used it

Answer (score 5):

You could use a regular expression. `\\d+` will match consecutive digits. Also, I'd suggest a `do-while` loop. Something like

```
int quantity = -1;
do {
    input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Food quantity",
            "Dope Alley", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    if (input.matches("\\d+")) {
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
} while(quantity < 1 || quantity > 100);
```

Comment: Maybe `"\\d{1,8}"` to prevent smarty-pants overflow :)

Comment: if the quantity is -1 , i think if the user put 0 it will proceed

Comment: @ZaemShakkir No, because `0` and `-1` are less than `1`.

Comment: okay , i'll try . then how do i want to make user input 0 then display error message

Comment: You could keep another count of how many times the loop has run, and display an error message if it isn't the first time.

Comment: is it possible if i'm using try and catch ?

Comment: please see my updated answer above and how do i simply that code .